# addition and subtraction sum attribute

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I need to do an addition if the `type_In` == "In" and a subtraction if the `type_In` == "Out"

the `sum` attribute does just the addition

```html
<field name="type_In"/>
<field name="Amount_In" sum="Amount total"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a better why only if you are good
in javascipt.

try to add a compute field.

```py
Amount_value = fields....(compute="_get_amout_value") # same field type as Amount_In

@api.depends('Amount_In')
def get_amout_value(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.type_In == "In":
            rec.Amount_value = rec.Amount_In
        else :
            rec.Amount_value = rec.Amount_In * -1
```

and if the tree:

```xml
    <field name="type_In"/>
    <field name="Amount_value" sum="Amount total"/>
```

Comment: thanks for answering, I'll pray for u even I've already solved it

Comment: Thank you but did you use same solutions.